# how to avoid outofMemory error due to String variable

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory

I have big data input xml files which I am parsing using stax parser and then I am storing a set of specific tag values to txt file. I am having 4 cases to check  but everytime after 2 nd check its giving outof memory error at

```
for (String conversa: p_convers) {
    converInfo += conversa + "-----"; 
}
```

At this line a huge set of paragraph text will be added by many users and then I will store it to file.

To avoid this stage of memory issue I have added VM var arguments at Eclipse as below at Run configuration

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

with this settings it will run successfully with warning message as

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

How to avoid these things and use stable code?

Comment: Use StringBuilder - it's much more memory efficient.

Comment: Regarding warning. Permgen was replaced by metaspace in java 8.  Metaspace is able to autoincrease it's size (unlike permgen), But if you need to limit it's size you can use `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize`.

Comment: Can you add the Strings in the file inside the loop each time, instead of building a huge string then putting it all in a file ? Also, how many characters are there in each conversa approximatively ?

Comment: If StringBuilder then many of string functions I cant use like I will be checking with   if(converInfo.endsWith("=====")){
        converInfo = converInfo.substring(0, converInfo.length()-5);
       }   These things are difficult with stringbuilder. Finally Its my local machine .. if I executed in linux server same with same vm arguments and 32gb RAM does this solves or it may crash any time?

Answer (score 1):

Up to [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) command `MaxPermSize` has been removed and changed by

```
-XmxNNNm
```

i.e (as you already did)

```
-Xmx1024m
```

In order to avoid this warning just delete it.

If you continue having memory errors, put more memory to the server.

---

Now, your code:

```
for (String conversa: p_convers) {
    converInfo += conversa + "-----"; 
}
```

NEVER, NEVER use string concatenation inside a loop, this is why StringBuilder was born:

```
private final String SEPARATOR = "-----";

....

StringBuilder converInfo = new StringBuilder();
for (String conversa: p_convers) {
    converInfo.append(conversa);
    converInfo.append(SEPARATOR);

}
```

Comment: with StringBuilder also same thing any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` to concatenate strings. If you use `+` then each time you create new string instance e.g. in line from loop you create three strings (lets say in `conversa` you got 'conversa' value):

- `conversa`
- `conversa-----`
- `converterInfoconversa-----`

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered, first replace string concatenation with StringBuilder. If it does not help, change the algorithm.

```
"At this line a huge set of paragraph text will be added by many users and then I will store it to file. "
```

Instead of creation of one big buffer, try to write smaller chunks to the file just after reading them.